# When using pip install, why is the list of (from versions: xxx) very short?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, pypi, pypiserver

The following is the output I got on server1.
[image]

The following is the output I got on server2.
[image]

This results in that I cannot download older versions of some packages (e.g. tensorflow-gpu) on server1. Why are they different? What's wrong?

Comment: Since neither of them has 1.12.3, what happens if you try to install 1.12.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things going on here. First, it looks like the Tuna mirror is not mirroring pre-releases (ending in `rc1`, `rc2`, `a0`, etc.)

If we just consider PyPI, on "server1" you're getting the following releases:

- `1.13.0rc1`
- `1.13.0rc2`
- `1.13.0`
- `2.0.0a0`

These are all the releases that [support Python 3.7](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17022#issuecomment-462872123), so my guess is that you are using Python 3.7 on "server1", and some other, older version of Python on "server2", and `pip` is filtering compatible releases for you.